# Run Python from C++ on Android using NDK

Tags: python, android, c++, java-native-interface, cpython

I want to run some Python code from Android through JNI using NDK like this:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <Python.h>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_mypythonapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */)
{
    std::string command = "print('Hello World from Python!!!')";

    PyObject* pInt;

    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString(command.c_str());

    Py_Finalize();

    std::string message = "Command ";
    message.append(command);
    message.append(" was executed successfully!")

    return env->NewStringUTF(message.c_str());
}
```

Are there prebuilt `libpython` available for Android or is there any way to cross compile it in order to be able to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Compile `Python` for `Android` with:

```
┌─[19:20:55]─[jacob@jacob-pc]─[~]
└──> export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path/to/android-ndk

┌─[19:20:55]─[jacob@jacob-pc]─[~]
└──> ./configure CC=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang  CXX=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang++ AR=aarch64-linux-android-ar LD=aarch64-linux-android-ld RANLIB=aarch64-linux-android-ranlib --target=arm-linux-androideabi -prefix=/path/to/install/dir --enable-shared --without-sqlite3 --without-pdo-sqlite --without-pear --enable-simplexml --disable-mbregex --enable-sockets --enable-fpm --disable-opcache --enable-libxml --without-zlib --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-all --disable-ipv6 ac_cv_have_long_long_format=yes ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=no ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no

┌─[19:20:55]─[jacob@jacob-pc]─[~]
└──> make

┌─[19:20:55]─[jacob@jacob-pc]─[~]
└──> make install
```

Or, easier, [using docker](https://github.com/yan12125/python3-android):

```
┌─[19:20:55]─[jacob@jacob-pc]─[~]
└──> docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/python3-android -v /path/to/android-ndk:/android-ndk:ro --env ARCH=arm --env ANDROID_API=21 python:3.9.0-slim /python3-android/docker-build.sh
```

replacing `/path/to/android-ndk` with the path to the Android NDK.

2. Deploy the resulted folder inside an readable folder on your `Android` system then call `Py_SetPythonHome` providing that path.
3. Be aware that it is probably necessary to run:

```
Py_Initialize();
std::string command = "print('hello world')";
PyRun_SimpleString(command.c_str());
Py_Finalize();
```

on a thread other than the Java thread.

Tested with `21.1.6352462`, `Python 3.8.6` and `Python 3.9.0`.

Comment: Can you explain all the flags? I feel like not all of them are essential, and I can't determine which ones I actually need to compile with python

Comment: does `./configure --help` help with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/). To see various tools to run python on android [this](https://medium.com/@umerfarooq_26378/tools-to-run-python-on-android-9060663972b4) article will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Python is available only for using under host:

```
~/ndk/21.3.6528147$ find -iname *py*.so -o -iname *py*.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so
```

Comment: That's all there is in the NDK, but AOSP has more, but it also seems to be for under-host use only.

Comment: I need it for `android-arm` and `android-arm64`, unfortunately...so `linux-x86_64` doesn't help me very much

Comment: Yes, it is true.